# PowerPoint 2016 Presentation.Close does NOT remove entry from Application.Presentations

Tags: vba, powerpoint

### Settings

- PowerPoint 2016
- .NET com-addin (CP 4) with

  - WindowActivate DISPID(2009)
  - for test purposes changed to just "do nothing but the necessities"
- Windows 10
- Create an empty file in a folder using windows explorer (no slides
  inside said file).

### Problem description

Using integrated VBA i ran this code three times

```
Option Explicit    
Sub test()
    Dim objPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set objPresentation = Application.Presentations.Open("c:\test\folder\file.pptx")
    objPresentation.Close
    Set objPresentation = Nothing
    Debug.Print Presentations.Count
    For Each objPresentation In Presentations
        Debug.Print objPresentation.FullName, vbTab, objPresentation.Windows.Count
    Next
End Sub
```

Please find result below

```
 2 
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\kh_tests.pptm                     1 
c:\test\folder\file.pptx                   0 
 3 
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\kh_tests.pptm                     1 
c:\test\folder\file.pptx                   0 
c:\test\folder\file.pptx                   0 
 4 
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\kh_tests.pptm                     1 
c:\test\folder\file.pptx                   0 
c:\test\folder\file.pptx                   0 
c:\test\folder\file.pptx                   0
```

It confuses not only my addin (is a presentation open or not), it seems not to be intentional since one could expect ppt would at least *reuse* the entry it left behind last time, but the entry seems to be corrupt.

I've encountered this behavior on several systems with PPT2016.

PPT2010 does *not* show this behavior.
Thank you for reading
KH

### Explanation/Hypothesis

I *think* i came closer to the reason (sorry for the time it took but you know how it is some times); i came to the believe that "someone" is still pointing to that particular presentation so it might not close; so i decided to have another go for it.

I narrowed it down by selective disabling everything in my com-addin, but to no result: even doing *nothing* (just "return") the behavior remains the same; but if i did not connect my connection-point (**WindowActivate**, DISPID 2009) in the first place it suddenly worked and all went well. According to my logfile the event has always been processed after the close, not interfering with anything, but who knows. I tried to force things with DoEvents, but to no avail.

Hypothesis:
The presence of WindowActivate event sinks will keep PowerPoint2016 from discarding the presentation *WHICH HAS BEEN ACTIVE* at that time, even if closing *this* presentation is the reason for the event in the first place.

Test:
Unfortunately i found no easy way to have an vba/inapp test. Any ideas?

But with my fully fledged com addin present (okay, still much deactivated, by sink connected), i tested this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objCloak As PowerPoint.Presentation

Sub test()
    Dim objPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set objPresentation = Application.Presentations.Open("C:\test\folder\file.pptx")

    If objCloak Is Nothing Then
        Set objCloak = Presentations.Add ' change to the intermediate presentation
    End If

    DoEvents                         ' relic from previous tests
    objCloak.Windows(1).Activate '   ' be paranoid

    DoEvents                         ' relic from previous tests
    objPresentation.Close
    DoEvents                         ' relic from previous tests

    If (Not (Nothing Is objCloak)) Then
        objCloak.Saved = True
        objCloak.Close
    End If
    Set objCloak = Nothing

    For Each objPresentation In Presentations
        Debug.Print objPresentation.FullName, vbTab, objPresentation.Windows.Count
    Next

End Sub
```

And the result is

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\kh_tests.pptm                     1 
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\kh_tests.pptm                     1 
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\kh_tests.pptm                     1
```

Switch back and force between the two variants yields the results as described above. So i think there's something here.

Note: the PowerPoint Task now closes without any problems.

Comment: Possibly a bug in PPT 2016.  I can't repro this here in PPT 2016 (aka 365) 32-bit, Insider Fast running under Win7/64.

Comment: Thank you. This also happens, if i run similar code using .NET interop (clientprofile/4).I just tried to do a "pure vba/no addins/everything to out-of-the-box" approach to confirm it.

Comment: Please note the edited text above; it seems i found a "solution" (more like a workaround) for avoiding this behavior; and as far as i can tell i found the condition for this behavior.